# Best resources for developing swing applications in java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, open-source

My boss would like me to debug an open-source java application written in swing, and has suggested the eclipse IDE.  I have picked up Eclipse IDE, read it, and am working on reading Headfirst Design Patterns.
I'm well on my way, but would like to ask you what resources(books, websites, pluggins) are best for de-bugging java swing applications in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hands down, the easiest way to make your swing program easy to debug is to get rid of swing.

I shouldn't say it like that. I love swing. I'm just saying if you can't do EVERYTHING your program does from the command line instead of your gui, you're going to have a hard time debugging it.

Where you can, refactor the code so that it's easy to call it from a command line, passing in the arguments like that, and then you can debug the individual components as you go.

Once they are working to your satisfaction, then the swing part is just a matter of hooking up the gui to the backend.

This pattern is part of what is often called MVC.

Comment: This could be summarized as ensuring that you ensure that the process and the application must not be mixed. In the swing classes you need only the code to draw the swing and manage events and, at most, one or two calls (per method) to the application classes (who know nothing about swing). This will also help to write a testsuite, if needed later. Of course, refactoring may take some work so decide if it is worth it (are you going to constantly debug/modify the app or is this a "just once" thing?)

Comment: @Sjuan those are some excellent points, even if your summary is almost as long as my post. :-) Separating logic from front-end is the key (in ANY environment.) The testability aspect is also very important. And in my experience, **there are no "just once" things!**